# H2O Python. Cant get ACU

Tags: python, h2o

I am learning h2o model predictions. When I do:

```
data_frame = h2o.H2OFrame(python_obj=data[1:], column_names=data[0])
data_train, data_valid, data_test = data_frame.split_frame(ratios= config.trainer_analizer_ratios, seed=config.trainer_analizer_seed)

# H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
allLog += "/n Starting H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator"
model_gle = h2o.estimators.H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator()
model_gle.train(x=predictors, y=response, training_frame= data_train, validation_frame= data_valid)
print(model_gle)
perf_gle = model_gle.model_performance(test_data= data_test)
print("GBM Precision:",perf_gle)
```

I get the following output

```
** Reported on test data. **

MSE: 494.25950875189955
RMSE: 22.23194792976764
MAE: 17.380709221249717
RMSLE: 1.217426465475652
R^2: 0.04331665117221439
Mean Residual Deviance: 494.25950875189955
Null degrees of freedom: 1177
Residual degrees of freedom: 1174
Null deviance: 608812.1064795277
Residual deviance: 582237.7013097376
AIC: 10660.224689554776
```

Why don't I get the `ACU` metric? I need that to score different models.

Answer (score 1):

The GLM algo thinks you are solving a regression problem. You need to specify that you are solving a classification problem. You can do this with the family parameter (please see the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/family.html) for an example) and possibly you need to set your target to type `enum` using the `asfactor()` method.

For your convenience here is the example code snippet that the link points to:

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
h2o.init()

# import the cars dataset:
# this dataset is used to classify whether or not a car is economical based on
# the car's displacement, power, weight, and acceleration, and the year it was made
cars = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/junit/cars_20mpg.csv")

# convert response column to a factor
cars["economy_20mpg"] = cars["economy_20mpg"].asfactor()

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors = ["displacement","power","weight","acceleration","year"]
response = "economy_20mpg"

# split into train and validation sets
train, valid = cars.split_frame(ratios = [.8])

# try using the `family` parameter:
# Initialize and train a GLM
cars_glm = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family = 'binomial')
cars_glm.train(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, validation_frame = valid)

# print the auc for the validation data
cars_glm.auc(valid = True)
```

Comment: Dont works. If i put the response as factor got the following error: `ERRR on field: _response: Regression requires numeric response, got categorical`

Comment: are you saying that the code snippet above doesn't work for you, or that your code didn't work. You need to specify that your `family = binomial` with `H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family = 'binomial')` in addition to converting the target to a categorical. Note that your error is saying your algorithm still thinks you are doing a regression problem, but that you have successfully converted your target to type categorical.